# Python - is there any way to expand the resolution ratio for existing Tkinter Tk() and Toplevel() widget? (zooming-in)

Tags: python, tkinter

I just made an app using python and tkinter widgets. 

 There are Labels, Frames, Buttons, etc in the Tk and Toplevel widgets.

However, it includes thousands of codes and its really annoying to resize every widgets when I support multiple resolutions.

Is there any way to expand the resolution ratio for existing Tkinter Tk() and Toplevel() widget and their child widgets? (zooming-in)

 If not, what would be the best approach to support multiple resolutions of a python app with the same ratio?

 Any help would be much appreciated, sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible however it depends on the geometry manager you have used in your program.

---

For the `.pack()` method (which is arguably the *simplest* geometry method for "intelligent" GUI designs) you can use a range of attributes on when you declare `.pack()` on the widget. These attributes include (but are not limited to) `fill`, `expand`, `anchor`, `padx`, `pady`, etc.

The below shows an example of a set of three buttons which will automatically expand to fit the window if it changes or is initialised to a different size than was used during development.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

btn1 = Button(root, text="btn1")
btn2 = Button(root, text="btn2")
btn3 = Button(root, text="btn3")

btn1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
btn2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
btn3.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

---

For the `.grid()` method you will need to make use of the functions `Grid.columnconfigure()` and `Grid.rowconfigure`. Both of these have the attribute `weight` which determines which rows and columns should be given priority for assignment of extra space if more becomes available in the window. Setting all rows and columns to have a `weight` of 1 means they will all be given space equally. You will also need to use the `sticky` attribute when declaring `.grid()` on the widgets.

The below shows an example of a set of three buttons which will automatically expand to fit the window if it changes or is initialised to a different size than was used during development.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

for column in range(3):
    Grid.columnconfigure(root, column, weight=1)

for row in range(1):
    Grid.rowconfigure(root, row, weight=1)

btn1 = Button(root, text="btn1")
btn2 = Button(root, text="btn2")
btn3 = Button(root, text="btn3")

btn1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
btn2.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
btn3.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

root.mainloop()
```

---

Using `.place()` would be a lot more difficult, you would need to have a function setup which would trigger on every window resize event which would calculate the size that the buttons need to expand to.

This would look something like the below:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.button = Button(self.root, text="Button")
        self.button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")
        self.root.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)
    def resize(self, *args):
        self.button.configure(width=self.root.winfo_width(), height=self.root.winfo_height())

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

Subjectively speaking, `.pack()` tends to be easier, however this all comes down to how much effort you're willing to put in to implement this with your current program.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment so I add a short tip to the detailed Ethan answer. You can design most of the GUIs in tkinter with either pack,  grid or a combination of both (by placing frames on a window with one of them, and using either grid or pack inside of each frame, to "place" the widgets). You can tune the configurations for proper location and size when the window resizes. Keep placer use for special cases (like overlaying some widget on the top of others)